# Onchange image change javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It must be very simple, but can't find correct variant.
I need to change image in select with onchange function but take instead of value attribute data-ima.

```
 <select onchange="changeSelection(this)" id="bundle-option-1550" name="bundle_option">
  <option value="5356" data-ima="pic.jpg">1</option>
  <option value="5357" data-ima="pic1.jpg">2</option>
  <option value="5358" data-ima="pic2.jpg">3</option>
  <option value="5359" data-ima="pic3.jpg">4</option>
</select>
 <img id="bundle"  src=""/>
```

and javascript which I use

```
function changeSelection(elem) {
var op = $(elem).find(':selected').data('ima')
var image = document.getElementById("bundle"),
image.src = elem.op;}
```

Comment: `image.src = elem.op` – your local variable inside the function is named `op`, so why are you using `elem.op` here …?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/f7ek36xa/1/)

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#bundle-option-1550").change(function(){
        var dataimg = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-ima");

        $("#bundle").attr("src",dataimg);

    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome and glad to hear this

Answer (score 1):

Use `.attr()` to set the src of the image

```
jQuery("#bundle-option-1550").on('change', function(e){
    var op = $(this).find('option:selected').data('ima');
    $("#bundle").attr('src', op);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#bundle-option-1550").on('change', function(e){
    var op = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-ima');
    document.getElementById("bundle").src = op;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code works if you change the last line of your javascript function from

```
image.src = elem.op;}
```

to

```
image.src = op;}
```